# How to sort the kendo treeview based on child node count

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm new to kendo treeview. Now i'm facing some issue with treeview. My treeview is showing like below :

[image]

Those tow **PDF** are under `3.2.S` Parent folder. But they are not in proper order. I need to place those two **PDF** at once and folders at once like below image :

[image]

Kindly help me to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may be achieved by apply sort to your datasource

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: ...,
  sort: { field: "field_name", dir: "asc" }
});
```

or sort the child nodes

```
asc= new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
          sort: { field: "field_name", dir: "asc" },
```

[Documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/navigation/treeview/how-to/binding/sort-child-nodes)

Comment: "field_name" is it property name my dataset name? and in second option "asc" where do i need to assingn it?

Comment: correct, the asc or desc variable will be assigned to your data source as the example on the documentation. You can also dynamically revert the sort. Please check the sort sample on the documentation